# NodeJS stream a remote file and zip it, and store it locally

Tags: node.js, streaming, node-streams

I am trying to download a remote file, and zip it and save it into locally  in node server.
I am using node 8.11.4

The code run correctly if I didn't zip it, but when I zip it, it stop working

So, the following code is working

```
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')

const url = remoteurl // a url that is pointing to a pdf file
https.get(url, (res) => {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./local-pdf.pdf"))
  .on('finish', () => {
     console.log('you finished')
   })
})
```

The above code will save correctly the pdf file.

But when I try to zip it on the stream, like this

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const https = require('https')

const url = remoteurl
https.get(url, (res) => {
  res.
   pipe(zlib.createGzip())
   pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./local-zip.zip"))
  .on('finish', () => {
     console.log('you finished')
   })
})
```

It generates a zip file, but when I open it in, it tells me it is not a valid zip file. Although if I zip the file using zlib locally, it is working fine

Is there something I have to do on the pipe?

Comment: I'd start by comparing headers of the two files. At least both should begin with the gzip magic header (ie. 0x1f 0x8b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to understand what isn't working for you. Your code has a few typos, so it shouldn't run in the first place, but if you fix these typos it works just fine for me.

Which programm do you use trying to open the `.zip`?

*(By the way: maybe consider making the file end on `.gz`, because that's the proper file ending for gzip compressed data)*

Comment: You are right. it was supposed to be .gz.
and I will fix the typo